# Стилизация checkbox в EDGE

Tags: html, css, checkbox, microsoft-edge

В EDGE у меня все checkbox-ы зелёные. Как это исправить и заменить их на белые?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="radio"]::-ms-check, input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type=radio name=a>
<input type=radio name=a checked>
<input type=radio name=a>
<input type=radio name=a>

<br>

<input type=checkbox name=b>
<input type=checkbox name=b checked>
<input type=checkbox name=b>
<input type=checkbox name=b>
```

В IE11 выглядит вот так (в Edge тоже должно работать):

[image: Cкриншот из IE11 на Win7]